# Calculate duration of work and break period of employees from time sheet data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language, gs-vlookup

Have two Google sheets 
timesheet (data is appended from an RFID reader)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T_ZbPub9CV_-S5Ve5OxtlPoGfvV8uXkxxoKnUGBuXPo/edit?usp=sharing
would like to have a duration of employee worked and break period in a month. (employee can take multiple breaks in a day)
for a given day always first punch is IN and the second is OUT which would give the duration of time he has worked. the rest would be break period

result sheet (monthly attendance)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IWu1eJCtG3LQQYfF2N5Hd02rZ2t3GfgbjOoYQbQuQFk/edit?usp=sharing

As the data is one column duno how to achieve iteration for a given day.

[image: monthly attendance]
[image: Result expected]

Comment: This looks difficult because I can't see how you tell whether they're signing in or signing out

Comment: pls add some example of desired output

Comment: @TomSharpe for any given day the first is IN and the second is OUT. Thanks have add this info in description now

Comment: @player0 have edited and add the desired result output.

Comment: @kanted Did one of these answers help you do what you wanted (tally the worked time for an employee)? If so, upvote /accept. Suddenly requiring error handling is not something that should be asked after already receiving answers IMO. You could ask a new SO question for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you will need some prep work. see columns **J:O**:

[image: 0]

then you can do simple `HLOOKUP`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(A24:24, QUERY(QUERY({Sheet2!J1:O}, 
 "select Col1,day(Col1),sum(Col5),sum(Col6),Col4 
  where month(Col1)+1="&B23&" 
  group by Col1,Col4 
  format Col1'd'", 0), 
 "select Col5,"&IF(D23="Break", "sum(Col4)", "sum(Col3)")&" 
  where Col5 is not null
  group by Col5
  pivot Col2
  label Col5'Employee names'", 1), ROW(A2:A20), 0)))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KIR7YWJlHBD9gMmFPw7zL3d4Y0WZL4S4tN7vyiVJDRg/copy)

---

## UPDATE:

to fix the missing punch-out you can add a check:

```
={"punch-out check"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&C2:C, QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&C2:C, 
 COUNTIFS(A2:A&C2:C, A2:A&C2:C, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))},
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"),
 "where not Col2 >1 offset 1", 0), 2, 0)))}
```

[image: 1]

---

then the formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date","Start", "End", "Name";
 {ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(SORT(FILTER({timesheet!A2:B, timesheet!E2:E}, timesheet!F2:F<>1), 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1), 
 MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("timesheet!A1:A"&ROWS(timesheet!A2:A)-COUNTIF(timesheet!F2:F, 1))), 2)), 
 ROWS(timesheet!A2:A)-COUNTIF(timesheet!F2:F, 1), 2)}, 
 QUERY(FILTER(SORT(FILTER({timesheet!A2:B, timesheet!E2:E}, timesheet!F2:F<>1), 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1), 
 MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("timesheet!A2:A"&ROWS(timesheet!A2:A)-COUNTIF(timesheet!F2:F, 1)+1)), 2)), "select Col2, Col3", 0)})
```

[image: 9]

---

and dashboard would list it like:

```
={"Didn't punched out"; FILTER(timesheet!E2:E, timesheet!A2:A=C2, timesheet!F2:F=1)}
```

[image: 9]

Comment: you seem to be god of google sheets. So simplified approach. How to overcome the limitation of range in first array formula. `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(SORT({A2:B, E2:E}, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1), MOD(ROW(A1:A1001), 2)), ROWS(A2:A), 2)`
if we change A1:A1001 to full range A1:A or A:A it fails. As this sheet would be continuously append don't want range limitation.

Comment: @Kanted you can do: `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(SORT({A2:B, E2:E}, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1), MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROWS(A2:A))), 2)), ROWS(A2:A), 2)`

Comment: Thanks that did resolve. But this approach has a challenge it breaks if an employee has missed anyone of his card punch for the day. [link] (ibb.co/3WbTyV6) Either we need to show it as a card punch error for such days/employee in the result or ppbly some other way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it as

```
Sum of even times - Sum of odd times

=ArrayFormula(sumif(iferror(iseven(rank(if((timesheet!$E2:$E=$A3)*(timesheet!$A2:$A=date(2019,$B$1,O$2)),timesheet!$B2:$B),if((timesheet!$E2:$E=$A3)*(timesheet!$A2:$A=date(2019,$B$1,O$2)),timesheet!$B2:$B),1)),false),true,timesheet!$B2:$B)-
sumif(iferror(isodd(rank(if((timesheet!$E2:$E=$A3)*(timesheet!$A2:$A=date(2019,$B$1,O$2)),timesheet!$B2:$B),if((timesheet!$E2:$E=$A3)*(timesheet!$A2:$A=date(2019,$B$1,O$2)),timesheet!$B2:$B),1)),false),true,timesheet!$B2:$B))
```

Here's how it looks on the whole sheet:

[image]

**EDIT**

With a check that number of punches in/out is even:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isodd(countifs(timesheet!$E$2:$E,$A3,timesheet!$A$2:$A,date(2019,$B$1,O$2))),"Error",sumif(iferror(iseven(rank(if((timesheet!$E$2:$E=$A3)*(timesheet!$A$2:$A=date(2019,$B$1,O$2)),timesheet!$B$2:$B),if((timesheet!$E$2:$E=$A3)*(timesheet!$A$2:$A=date(2019,$B$1,O$2)),timesheet!$B$2:$B),1)),false),true,timesheet!$B$2:$B)-
sumif(iferror(isodd(rank(if((timesheet!$E$2:$E=$A3)*(timesheet!$A$2:$A=date(2019,$B$1,O$2)),timesheet!$B$2:$B),if((timesheet!$E$2:$E=$A3)*(timesheet!$A$2:$A=date(2019,$B$1,O$2)),timesheet!$B$2:$B),1)),false),true,timesheet!$B$2:$B)))
```

[image]

Comment: how would you suggest to handle when employee has missed one of his punch. leaving the final  as odd counts for a given day

Comment: I would check if the total punches for the day is odd or even using countifs, and report an error if it's odd. Will add to my answer.